# Is it possible to init AdminController from outside Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am trying to initiate the AdminController module from outside the Prestashop. Basically, I am creating an external program which uses Prestashop to get current employee for which I should instantiate the AdminController, but its throwing error.

Many modules init the FrontController but I cannot find any example for AdminController like :

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../init.php');
```

Please advice.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you are trying to do? For what are you getting current employee ?

Comment: @user2831723 Sure, I have an external library where in I want to display the current logged in employee in the Prestashop when accessed from web browser. Both - external lib and Prestashop are installed on the same web server and can access each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after all. Simply define `_PS_ADMIN_DIR_` and init the `config.inc.php`, Prestashop will automatically load the admin environment.  However, if you are loading this from a module, its tricky to find the admin directory as its not defined anywhere, so I have written this small script.

```
$admindir = '';
foreach (glob("../../*/ajaxfilemanager", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $filename) {
    $admindir = str_replace('../../', '', $filename);
    $admindir = str_replace('/ajaxfilemanager', '', $admindir);

}
define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd().'/../../'.$admindir);
require(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/../config/config.inc.php');
```

Enjoy!